# Internal Server Error occured when error happens in php file

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I will get an `Internal Server Error` when error occured in php file in live server.

I've folder `test` with  a file `test.php`,when i generate syntax error in `test.php` i will get `Internal server error`.
Rerferd many of  the stackoverflow posts but didn't get an exact solution.

**Note**

1.added `ini_set('display_errors', 1`) in `test.php`.

2.added  `php_flag display_errors 1` in `.htaccess` file which is in `test` folder.

Also an error file is generated in `test` folder it contains the php errors.

Full error displayed in browser window.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@zama.in and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: try it with `error_reporting( E_ALL);`

Comment: again the same result

Comment: This is network related issue, just for testing change your file name and run.

Comment: @Blessan, all other pages are working fine?

Comment: when there is no error in php pages it will working dfine,but if an error is occured(syntax error) ,will get internal server error

Comment: no, i told you its network related error not code error, please check your other pages, are they working or same issue?

Comment: Check your .htaccess file for errors, try to remove .htaccess and run a sample .php file and see if the error is still there.

Comment: all pages get internal server error

Comment: @Nikhil its worked partially  ,created another file sample.php its worked,but the test.php (note taht test.php have a synatx error)get another error  server error 500

Comment: Do you have access to edit php.ini file?

Comment: nop im using shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

1. Error in your .htaccess file (check .htaccess and fix if there is any errors).
2. PHP syntax errors are not showing because the error logging needs to enabled in php.ini file.

[image]

If still proble persists, contact your shared hosting provider and ask them to provide the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution
Create a php.ini file in my root folder and added the following to it

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php" 
display_errors = On
```

Now i will get the errors in browser window